# В какой момент заполняется матрица переходов (Таблица виртуальных функций)экземпляра класса-потомка?

Tags: c++, ооп

Терминология с++:
функция-член класса =  метод

Мы все знаем, что переопределение функции-члена класса при использовании ключевого слова `virtual` ведёт к тому, что метод, вызванный по ссылке или указателю экземпляра класса будет определяться в процессе выполнения программы(если я ничего не путаю, если вызывать по названию экземпляра, то этот механизм не работает, метод так же определяется на этапе компиляции). На всякий случай цитата из Праты 6 издание:

> Без ключевого слова virtual программа выбирает метод, основываясь на
> типе ссьтки или указателя . Но если присутствует ключевое слово virtual ,
> программа выбирает метод, основываясь на типе объекта, на
> который указывает ссылка или указатель.

Так вот механизм этот, под капотом, работает с помощью матрицы переходов -  то есть, насколько я понял, у каждого экземпляра любого класса формируется своя матрица переходов с указателями на свои функции-члены класса.

1. Верно ли я понимаю, что у базовых классов, или классов вне наследственной иерархии такая матрица формируется при компиляции?
2. В какой момент исполнения программы такая матрица заполняется у экземпляров класса, которые унаследовали виртуальные функции-члены класса

Comment: Для каждого класса во время компиляции компилятор создаёт таблицу виртуальных функций. Каждый экземпляр класса хранит неизменный указатель на эту таблицу. Установка указателя - первое действие при создании экземпляра. В процессе конструирования указатель может переустанавливаться и указателей может быть несколько, но это уже другая история.

Comment: Процесс конструирования в вашем комментарии это процесс создания экземпляра класса?

Comment: матрица виртуальных функций одна на каждый класс. Каждый экземпляр объекта хранит у себя адрес этой матрицы.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher, да.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильное название - таблица виртуальных функций. Никогда не слышал, чтобы кто-то ее называл "матрицей переходов".

Сами таблицы заполняются во время компиляции. Во время выполнения в экземпляр класса записывается только указатель на правильную таблицу.

Насколько я понимаю, этот указатель устанавливается сразу перед заходом в тело конструктора, причем это отдельно делает каждый родитель. А при разрушении класса, они меняются в обратном порядке - каждый класс ставит свой указатель перед заходом в тело своего деструктора.

Это все очень примерно. Сочные подробности, как минимум для GCC и Clang-а, должны быть [вот тут](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html).